# Receive Error java.io.StreamCorruptedException While reading large binary file

Tags: java, binaryfiles, objectinputstream

I have a large binary file and I am trying to read from the file using ObjectStream.I receive the error

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at demo.FileRead.readFile(FileRead.java:16)
```

My  code to Read from the File is :

```
public static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/xyz/Documents/packets_in_store_stats"));
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);//Receive error at this point         

        DataAvailable[] ia = (DataAvailable[]) (ois.readObject());
            System.out.println(ia[0] + "," + ia[1] + "," + ia[2] + "," + ia[3]
                + "," + ia[4]);
    }
```

Am I missing something over here.

Comment: Does the file start the the hexa `CAFEBABE`? I have the feeling that the file you're trying to read is not a serialised object but something else (maybe another binary format). Can you share from where you got that file or how the file was created?

Comment: @Augusto No, the file starts with 00000000. It's in the exception.

Answer (score 0):

A binary file is not a serialized object stream unless you know otherwise, and this one isn't anyway, whatever you may think. You should either be using `DataInputStream`, not `ObjectInputStream`, or reviewing how you wrote the file.